# How to embed TradingView into Angular 8 project?

Tags: angular, tradingview-api

I am interested to know how can I embed the following TradingView's code to my Angular 8 project?

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_bac65"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "Light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "withdateranges": true,
  "range": "ytd",
  "hide_side_toolbar": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "show_popup_button": true,
  "popup_width": "1000",
  "popup_height": "650",
  "no_referral_id": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_bac65"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

I also like to know how can I feed my data from a `.csv` file or from a URL address(like BTC online price).

Comment: This one worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296351/embed-tradingview-into-angular-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve my problem like this:

1. I created a new component in my project and named it `tradingview`. Then I added the following code into the `tradingview.component.ts` file:

> ```
> import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
>
>
> declare const TradingView: any;
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app-tradingview',
>   templateUrl: './tradingview.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./tradingview.component.scss']
> })
>
>
>
> export class TradingviewComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
>
>   constructor() { }
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>   }
>
>   ngAfterViewInit(){
>     new TradingView.widget(
>       {
>       "width": 980,
>       "height": 610,
>       "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
>       "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
>       "theme": "Light",
>       "style": "1",
>       "locale": "en",
>       "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
>       "enable_publishing": false,
>       "withdateranges": true,
>       "range": "ytd",
>       "hide_side_toolbar": false,
>       "allow_symbol_change": true,
>       "show_popup_button": true,
>       "popup_width": "1000",
>       "popup_height": "650",
>       "no_referral_id": true,
>       "container_id": "tradingview_bac65"
>     }
>       );
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Then I added following code into the `tradingview.component.html` file:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div id="tradingview_bac65"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

And seems it works fine!

Comment: There's an error in the console saying `ReferenceError: TradingView is not defined`. Could you please help out with this?

Comment: @Madara: Did you add `import { TradingviewComponent } from './tradingview/tradingview.component';
` line into the `app.module.ts` file of your project?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67231441/790635 to dynamically inject it instead

Comment: How is the code going to know what new TradingView.widget is? importing your TradingViewComponent is not the same thing, this widget is external, needs some other import