# TradingView widget not working in angular component

Tags: angular, tradingview-api

I am trying to use [Market Overview Widget](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/market-overview/) and [Single Ticker Widget](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/single-ticker/) in an Angular component itself but widgets don't load. I tried putting those in index.html and they rendered there but i need them in a component. I also tried putting script link in head tag but that didn't help either.

*Here's what I've got so far*

> component.html

```
<div id="tradingview_bac66"></div>
```

> component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
new TradingView.widget({
  "container_id": "tradingview_bac66",
  "colorTheme": "dark",
  "dateRange": "12M",
  "showChart": true,
  "locale": "en",
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "largeChartUrl": "",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "showSymbolLogo": true,
  "showFloatingTooltip": false,
  "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 1)",
  "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 1)",
  "gridLineColor": "rgba(42, 46, 57, 0)",
  "scaleFontColor": "rgba(134, 137, 147, 1)",
  "belowLineFillColorGrowing": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.12)",
  "belowLineFillColorFalling": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.12)",
  "belowLineFillColorGrowingBottom": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0)",
  "belowLineFillColorFallingBottom": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0)",
  "symbolActiveColor": "rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.12)",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "title": "Indices",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:TSLA",
          "d": "Tesla Motors, Inc"
        },
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:AMZN",
          "d": "Amazon.com Inc"
        },
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
          "d": "Apple"
        }
      ],
      "originalTitle": "Indices"
    }
  ]
})
}
```

> index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Vynity</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post that helped me. They've used renderer2 which worked for me also. I am on Angular14 so if you have the same problem as me this will work just fine for you too

[ERROR ReferenceError: TradingView is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993416/error-referenceerror-tradingview-is-not-defined/67231441#67231441)